# Get Input data from text box and send to calculate class?

Tags: c#, winforms, oop

So, I want to add number into text box form

[image]

and i want to send number to this class

```
public class ParticleSwarm
{

    private double Fitness;
    MatchedPart matchedParticle = new MatchedPart();
    public List<MatchedPart> m_listMatchedPartItem = new List<MatchedPart>();
    public List<MatchedPart> MatchedPartList
    {
        get
        {
            return m_listMatchedPartItem;
        }
    }
    public ParticleSwarm(double fitness)
    {           
        Fitness = fitness;
        Calculate();
        m_listMatchedPartItem.Add(matchedParticle);
    }        
    // Get data to winform

    public void Calculate()
    {

        int dim = 2; // problem dimensions 2
        int numParticles = 2; //2
        int maxEpochs = 100; //100
        double exitError = 0.0; // exit early if reach this error 0
        double minX = -10.0; // problem-dependent -10
        double maxX = 10.0; //10
```

How  I can replace number in text box to Calculate() dim, numParticles .. . . ?

Comment: you should get your textBoxes name and convert their `.Text` property using `int.Parse/int.TryParse` and `double.Parse/double.TryParse`

Comment: Calculate method should be changed to accept the parameters `dim` and `numparticles`. And from the `Form` you first need to convert the textbox.text to integer using `int.Parse` or `int.TryParse` and then call Calculate method by passing those values to it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You obviously need to have parameters to functions. If I understood your question correctly you want to pass the **Dimension** and **Particles** to the Calculate() function.

First, Inside **ParticleSwarm** Class, you should change the prototype of the function like below

```
 public void Calculate(int dimen,int numParts)
```

and when you want to call the method, just do like below

```
int dimen = int.Parse(textbox.Text);
int parts = int.Parse(textbox2.Text);
ParticleSwarm p = new ParticleSwarm();
p.Calculate(dimen,parts);
```

Your Calculate() function will look something like this

```
public void Calculate(int dimen,int numParts)
    {

        int dim = dimen; 
        int numParticles = numParts; 
        int maxEpochs = 100; //100
```

Though I am not sure that this is what you want!. Also, [Here](http://csharp.net-tutorials.com/basics/functions/) is a link on basics on C# functions and parameter passing should you require it!

**UPDATE 2**

According to your needs, the Constructor should be modified to look like this

```
public ParticleSwarm(double fitness,int dimen,int numParts)
    {           
        Fitness = fitness;
        Calculate(dimen,numParts);
        m_listMatchedPartItem.Add(matchedParticle);
    }
```

and call the constructor like this

```
 int dimen = int.Parse(textbox.Text);
    int parts = int.Parse(textbox2.Text);
    ParticleSwarm p = new ParticleSwarm(fitness,dimen,parts);
```

Comment: Yeah this is what i want . but i have a problem with ParticleSwarm()
.When i call ParticleSwarm() . I call Calculate() Inside of Method. It can't see Calculate(int dimen,int numParts); 
       
       


        {

Comment: Can you show me how and where you want to call Calculate()?

Comment: public ParticleSwarm(double fitness)
        {           
            Fitness = fitness;         
            Calculate();
            m_listMatchedPartItem.Add(matchedParticle);
        }

Comment: @MacN. Updated Answer

Answer (score 0):

You can call Calculate() method on button click and you can fetch the textbox values in Calculate() method or you can add the parameters to the Calculate(param 1, param 2) method and send the parameters value from fetching the values from textbox by using the below code:

```
int value = Convert.ToInt32(txtboxName.Text);
```

OR

```
double value = Convert.ToDouble(txtBoxName.Text);
```

Comment: I already know this part. but how to call Calculate() method. 
I call like this . private ParticleSwarm p;
p.Calculate();

Comment: Do you have any button in your form? If yes then you can call Calculate() Method on button click event.

Comment: You can use ParticleSwarm objParticleSwarm = new ParticleSwarm(); and then you can invoke objParticleSwarm.Calculate() method.